# Is the following substitution in the integral valid?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am a bit confused by my problem sheet. The problem is as follows:

Is $x = sin(t)$ a valid substitution in the integral: $\int_0^1{x}\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}dx$.

In the answers it just says no.

Why is that? Could someone elaborate to help me understand why this is?

Comment: *valid* in which sense? It can be most definitely applied as $x$ ranges between $0$ and $1$. But maybe it means that it is not of much use, as you can find the antiderivative by just staring long enough at the integrand...

Comment: Other substitutions that might be of interest: $u=1-x^2,v=\sqrt[3]{(1-x^2)^4},\dots$

Comment: It is valid.  It just might not be the most direct way to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather say it is a perfectly reasonable substitution:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(\theta)\cos^{\frac{5}{3}}(\theta)\,d\theta = \left.-\frac{3}{8}\cos^{\frac{8}{3}}(\theta)\right|_{0}^{\pi/2} = \color{red}{\frac{3}{8}}.$$

Comment: What about if the bounds where 0 and 2? Maybe it's a print mistake...

Comment: @n4869: in such a case such a substitution is not allowed since $\sin(\theta)\not\in(1,2]$ and change of variables are given by invertible maps.

Comment: Then it's probably that. I can't clearly see if it's a "1" or something else, supposed it was a "1".

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}x\root[3]{1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x} &\
\stackrel{x^{2}\ \to\ x}{=}\
\int_{0}^{1}x^{1/2}\pars{1 - x}^{1/3}\,\half\,x^{-1/2}\,\dd x =
\left.-\,{3 \over 8}\,\pars{1 - x}^{4/3}\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ 1} =
\color{#f00}{{3 \over 8}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the question, but I guess it is worth sharing.

I took the question to be

$\int^1_0x^3(\sqrt{1-x^2})$  $dx$

So, if we go your way, with $x=\sin{t}$

We get:

$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^3{t}.\cos^2{t}$  $dt$

$=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^3{t}.(1-\sin^2{t})$   $dt$

$=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^3{t}$  $dt$ $-\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^5{t}$   $dt$

By using Walli's theorem,

We get

$\frac{2}{3}-(\frac{2}{3}.\frac{4}{5})=\frac{2}{15}$